# SPFX Person field not rendering

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have a list with several fields and want to display this information in a spfx webpart. I have managed to get a date column displaying but I'm having issues displaying a person field. I want to display the person's name and the persons image.
The code gets the list items (though I will filter to one item later) and renders it to a table. Then the name of the Project Manager and Project Sponsor (Person fields) should be displayed with their images. So far, I cannot get the name to be displayed. The problem seems to be with:
${item.ProjectSponsor.FirstName}. I think it’s the wrong format or perhaps needs mapping?
PNP is not being used, but prepared to add pnp if required.

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import styles from './PwStatusWebPart.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'PwStatusWebPartStrings';


import * as moment from 'moment';



export interface IPwStatusWebPartProps {
  //description: string;
}


        export interface SPListItem {
          ProjectID: string;
        
          G1SchedDate: Date;
          G1StatusDate: Date;
          
          //ProjectSponsor: [FirstName: String ];
          ProjectSponsor: String;
          ProjectStatus: string;
        
        }
    
    
    export default class PwStatusWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IPwStatusWebPartProps> {
    
      private async getListData(): Promise<SPList> {
      
        const url = new URL(window.location.href);
        const proj = url.pathname;
        const projTitle = proj.slice(10, 17);
    
        const response = await this.context.spHttpClient.get("/sites/pw/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('My Projects')/Items?$select=Id,ProjectID,G1SchedDate,G1StatusDate,ProjectSponsor/FirstName,ProjectSponsor/EMail&$expand=ProjectSponsor", SPHttpClient.configurations.v1);
    
    
        return response.json();
      }
    
    
    
      private renderList(): void {
        this.getListData()
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
    
            let html: string = '<table border=0 width=100% style="border-collapse: collapse;" class = "space_status" >';
            html += '<th class = "header_status">G</th> <th class = "header_status">Scheduled Date</th><th class = "header_status">Approved Date</th>';
    
            response.value.forEach((item: SPListItem) => {
    
              html += `
              <tr >            
                <td>1</td> <td>${item.G1SchedDate ? moment(item.G1SchedDate).format('DD/MM/YY') : ""}</td> <td>${item.G1StatusDate ? moment(item.G1StatusDate).format('DD/MM/YY') : ""}</td>
              </tr>   
              </table></br/>
    
              ${item.ProjectSponsor.FirstName} // errors here
                  
                  `;
    
            });
    
    
            const listContainer: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#spListContainer');
            listContainer.innerHTML = html;
    
          }); 
      }
    
   
    
      public render(): void {
        this.domElement.innerHTML = `
    
      <div class="${styles.pwStatus}">
      <div class="${styles.container}">
      <div id = "spListContainer"></div>
      </div></div>
        `;
    
        this.renderList();
      }
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to check `hasOwnProperty`, you just need to check `if (item.ProjectSponsor.FirstName) { }`, that will evaluate to false if `FisrtName` is empty, null, or undefined.  If you want to be extra safe you could do `if (item.ProjectSponsor && item.ProjectSponsor.FirstName) { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a casing issue. The property on the JSON object is `EMail` but in your code you are asking for a property named `Email`.

**Correction:**

Sorry, I missed something in your code. The issue is with the `SPListItem` interface. Change it to this:

```
export interface SPUser {
  EMail: string;
  FirstName: string;
}

export interface SPListItem {
  ProjectID: string;
    
  G1SchedDate: Date;
  G1StatusDate: Date;
      
  //ProjectSponsor: [FirstName: String ];
  ProjectSponsor: SPUser;
  ProjectStatus: string;
}
```

Comment: I have tried EMail and FirstName but code does not compile
error TS2339: Property 'FirstName' does not exist on type 'string'.
I think its the way its been declared?

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed your declaration of the `SPListItem` interface. That's where the issue is. I added a correction to my answer.

Comment: Also, it's a standard convention that the names of interfaces begin with a capital letter I. So ISPListItem and ISPUser. It's not a huge thing but it will make it easier for other people to read your code,

Comment: Try `item.ProjectSponsor && item.ProjectSponsor.FirstName ? item.ProjectSponsor.FirstName : ""`. This will check to see if both item.ProjectSponsor and item.ProjectSponsor.FirstName are non-null. If they are it will display the first name, otherwise it will display an empty string.

Comment: Thanks, sorted it out, thanks. Finally, I want the user image displayed. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Thank you Rob, got it working!